# dovecot: can't open pid file

Tags: centos7, vps, dovecot, pid

im new here :) after 2 days of googling and trying whatever i could I can't get rid of this:

> systemd[1]: Can't open PID file /var/run/dovecot/master.pid (yet?) no such file or directory

i found info to change ownership of /var/run/dovecot/ to:

```
chown root:dovecot /var/run/dovecot

chmod 755 /var/run/dovecot
```

so after dovecot stop i'm using those commends and after that i'm starting dovecot, but master.pid is with:

```
-rw------- root:root
```

and from what i read it should be:

```
srwxr-xr-x root:dovecot
```

Clearly im doing something wrong but idont know what.

Comment: did you fix it? i have the same issue